# How to pass either one row or one column of 2D array into a function in java

Tags: java

I have One function like this

```
public int function1(int [][] arr) {
    for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < arr[].length; j++) {
            **uniqueH(arr[])**
        }
    }
}
```

In `UniqueH()` I want to pass only one row of 2D array.

```
UniqueH (int arr1[]) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't far off.  Just use the row number as the first index into your 2D array when you want to pass a single 1D slice as a row:

```
public int function1(int [][] arr) {
    for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        uniqueH(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Covering your need to slice a row **or** a column - you could adjust a little and use `Integer` instead of `int` and use an `Iterable`.

```
class Sliced<T> {
    final T[][] data;

    public Sliced(T[][] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Iterable<T> row(int i) {
        // Just make a list.
        return Arrays.asList(data[i]);
    }

    public Iterable<T> col(int i) {
        return new Iterable<T>() {

            @Override
            public Iterator<T> iterator() {
                return new Iterator<T>() {
                    int row = 0;

                    @Override
                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return row < data.length;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public T next() {
                        return data[row++][i];
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
}

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    Integer[][] a = {
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    };
    for ( Integer v : new Sliced<>(a).col(1)) {
        System.out.println(v);
    }
    for ( Integer v : new Sliced<>(a).row(1)) {
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```